# How to char converted into string..?

Tags: java, overloading

```
class Math {
    void Book1(char a, char b) {
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println("Output is" + c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Math m = new Math();
        m.Book1('A', 'B');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it is unclear to me what the question is in here. Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: String a = "" + 'c'; or String.valueOf('c');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Math {
    void Book1(char a, char b) {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(a);
        sb.append(b);
        System.out.println("Output is: " + sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Math m = new Math();
        m.Book1('A', 'B');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `String` class as follows:

```
public class Math {
    void Book1(char a, char b) {
        String str=String.valueOf(a)+String.valueOf(b);        
        System.out.println("Output is: " + str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Math m = new Math();
        m.Book1('A', 'B');
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Output is: AB
```